# Submitting a Form in Wordpress/Woocommerce admin order details

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

im trying to submit a form in order details if the order is processing. I have the button and field appearing and shows when the order is in processing. but when I submit it does nothing. im very sure im not got it right this is inside of a plugin. all the variables are there and work and display on the order page. so im only stuck on why when I press submit it does nothing at all.

```html
<?php
    if ($order_status1 == 'processing'){
//echo'<p><input type="text" name="sadd" id="sadd"><a href="?post=';echo $post_id;echo'&action=edit&abc=';echo $value;echo'" class="button">';echo"Add S to Order";echo'</a></p>';
    
        echo'<form action="#" method="post" id="astof" onSubmit="return confirm(';echo"'message that will display before submission?'";echo');">
            
<input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="text" name="sadd1">
             <button type="submit" class="woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-login__submit" form="astof" value="changes1" name="asto">Add Order</button>
          </form>';
    }
?>
<?php
            if(isset($_POST['astof'])){
                $resultsn = $_POST['sadd1'];
                $wpdb_dbconnectp = new wpdb('user', 'pass', 'Dan', 'localhost:3306');
$wpdb_dbconnectp->show_errors();
$sobject = $wpdb_dbconnectp->get_col("SELECT msisdn FROM s_stock WHERE idd = '$resultsn'");
foreach ($sobject as $sneeded) 
    $scutnoplus = substr($sneeded, 1);
        
    update_meta_data( $oiid, '_snumber',  $resultsn );
    update_post_meta( $gsn, '_snumber', $resultsn );
    update_post_meta( $gsn, '_s', $scutnoplus );
                
            }
    
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try manually adding [the action attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms_attributes.asp) to your form instead of #.
It seems that the button does not do it on its own.

Comment: If I change the button to goto asto name. this still does not submit the form either. but this code works in the my account page but not as admin pages?

Comment: <form action="url" method="post" id="astof">
<input class="woocommerce-Input woocommerce-Input--text input-text" type="text" name="sadd1">
 <input type="submit" class="woocommerce-button button woocommerce-form-login__submit" name="asto" value="Add/Update S to Order" >
          </form>

Comment: this code above just looks like it is posting in admin order details but doesn't goto the url it just refreshes the page I could but https://google.co.uk in the url page and it just refreshes the page?